# How can I prototype the jQuery "DOM" class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to create a function `inject()` that I can call on any jQuery DOM object.

For example, `$('div').inject()`, `$('#abc').inject()`, or even `$('nonStandardElement').inject()`;

I need to prototype it, because it should work for elements that have not been created yet.

What class (or set of classes) I can prototype to accomplish this?

Comment: You could define a plugin using jQuery. Check out http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Getting_Started unless you are adamant about prototyping the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). You add methods to jQuery's prototype object which is exposed as `jQuery.fn`:

```
jQuery.fn.inject = function inject() {
    /* do what you want */
    return this; // for chainability
};
```

Comment: Whats the advantage of fn over prototype?

Comment: It's official :-) From the source: `jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, figured it out!

Turns out I can add it right onto the 'jQuery' object, as in

```
jQuery.prototype.inject = function(x){alert('x')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write own jquery plugin like this,

```js
(function($){
 $.fn.inject= function() {

//code...
 };
})(jQuery);
```

```js
//Sample call
     $(selector).inject();
```